# Terraform I am getting count.index always 0

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

> Terraform v0.12.29 provider.aws v3.7.0

Terraform I am getting count.index always 0.

10.x0.0.0/23

```
resource "aws_subnet" "public" {
  count                   = length(var.availability_zones)
  vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.default.id
  cidr_block              = cidrsubnet(format("%s.%s.%s",join(".",slice(split(".",var.cidr_block), 0, 2)), count.index  ,split(".",var.cidr_block)[3]), var.public_newbits, count.index)
  availability_zone       = element(var.availability_zones, count.index)
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true
  tags                    = merge(map("Name", "${var.namespace}-${var.environment}-public-${count.index + 1}"), var.tags)
}
```

terraform plan

**cidr_block** value is 0 in both subnet.

```
# aws_subnet.public[0] will be created
  + resource "aws_subnet" "public" {
      + arn                             = (known after apply)
      + assign_ipv6_address_on_creation = false
      + availability_zone               = "ap-southeast-1a"
      + availability_zone_id            = (known after apply)
      + cidr_block                      = "10.x0.0.0/27"
      + id                              = (known after apply)
      + ipv6_cidr_block_association_id  = (known after apply)
      + map_public_ip_on_launch         = true
      + owner_id                        = (known after apply)
      + vpc_id                          = (known after apply)
    }

  # aws_subnet.public[1] will be created
  + resource "aws_subnet" "public" {
      + arn                             = (known after apply)
      + assign_ipv6_address_on_creation = false
      + availability_zone               = "ap-southeast-1b"
      + availability_zone_id            = (known after apply)
      + cidr_block                      = "10.x0.0.32/27"
      + id                              = (known after apply)
      + ipv6_cidr_block_association_id  = (known after apply)
      + map_public_ip_on_launch         = true
      + owner_id                        = (known after apply)
      + vpc_id                          = (known after apply)
    }
```

Comment: What is the form of `var.availability_zones`?

Comment: Could you also please clarify why you think `count.index` is zero? In which place it is zero only? Your terraform plan shows that its not zero as two subnets are created.

Comment: Please also specify the expected result for the two cidr_block outputs, and the full definition of var.cidr_block, the full definition of var.public_newbits.

Answer (score 0):

Here goes answer for my mistake. cidrsubnet() was quite tricky I took some time to understand it.

```
resource "aws_subnet" "public" {
  count                   = length(var.availability_zones)
  vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.default.id
  cidr_block              = cidrsubnet(var.cidr_block, var.public_newbits, count.index)
  availability_zone       = element(var.availability_zones, count.index)
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true
  tags                    = merge( var.tags, map("Name", "${var.environment}-${var.namespace}-mr-public-${count.index + 1}"))
}
```